# Using Python 3.4 and Pillow and the method transform: AttributeError: Image

Tags: python, transform, python-imaging-library

I have tried to make the following script running correctly:

```
def tftest():
    from PIL import Image
    picture = "ttamet3dim.png"
    impict = Image.open(picture)
    transf = impict.Image.transform((78,78), Image.QUAD, (78,41,178,27,183,91,81,91), Image.BICUBIC)
    imt = Image.open(transf)
    imt.show()
```

But I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python34\tftest.py", line 5, in tftest
    transf = impict.Image.transform(...)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pillow-3.0.0-py3.4-win32.egg\PIL\Image.py", line 626, in __getattr__
AttributeError: Image
```

It's the first time that I use `"transform"`. I wanted to have a look to the `"transform"` script to see if I could find out what's wrong but my `Pillow` is a `.egg` so I didn't find how to access to the code. Do you know why I get this error and how to fix it?
Thank you, best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've assigned the `Image` to the `impict` variable here:

```
impict = Image.open(picture)
```

you should reference this variable, that's the opened image, with the transform:

```
impict.transform
```

instead of what you're currently doing (basically `Image.open(picture).Image.transform`).

Comment: Thank you. It's working but "transform" is working in a different way from what I could find in documentation. Like if everything is opposite: normally I should give the 4 corners in counter clock-wise but I have to give them in clock-wise; normally I give first the row and then the column here it's the opposite. And the image that I get at the end is a rectangle with the correct size but it is also an axial symmetry. Why does it also make an axial symmetry? I though that "transform" should only change a quadrilateral into a rectangle with a given size.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a question/answer format -- open another question for where you're stuck with this now and someone will likely come along and help you.

Answer (score 2):

`transform` is a method for `Image` objects, and returns a new image:

```
from PIL import Image

def tftest():
    picture = "ttamet3dim.png"
    impict = Image.open(picture)
    imt = impict.transform((78,78), Image.QUAD, (78,41,178,27,183,91,81,91), Image.BICUBIC)
    imt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `transf = impict.Image.transform` to `transf = impict.transform`